# error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before, macro definition

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

i'm having trouble trying to define this function-like macro, which takes 4 vector magnitudes representing the major and minor axis of the top faces of a general cylinder and determines the type of general cylinder. EQUAL is an already defined macro to see if two floating point values are "equal" to one another.

```
3080 #define GET_TGC_TYPE(_type, _a, _b, _c, _d) { \
3081     if (EQUAL((_a), (_b)) && EQUAL((_c), (_d))) { \
3082         /* circular base and top */
3083         if (EQUAL((_a), (_c))) { \
3084             /* right circular cylinder */
3085             (_type) = RCC; \
3086         } else { \
3087             /* truncated right cone */
3088             (_type) = TRC; \
3089         } \
3090     } else { \
3091         /* elliptical base or top */
3092         if (EQUAL((_a), (_c)) && EQUAL((_b), (_d))) { \
3093             /* right elliptical cylinder */
3094             (_type) = REC; \
3095         } else { \
3096             /* truncated elliptical cone */
3097             (_type) = TEC; \
3098         } \
3099     }
3100 }
```

the errors i'm getting are

```
3083:9: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘if’
3086:11: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘else’
3090:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
3090:7: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘else’
3100:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
```

i dont have very much experience with C macros so its entirely possible i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: As someone who has had to maintain macros like this, I politely request that you throw out this entire implementation and rewrite it as a proper C function.  You can make it a static inline and stick it in a header file and it should behave exactly the same but without any of the potential macro side-effects of the current implementation.

Comment: @AndrewCottrell: i'm not opposed to that, could you explain some of the problems that could arise with the current macro?

Comment: @ChrisDueck: I believe your original post explains *one* of the problems that could arise with the current macro ;-)

Comment: @ChrisDueck, one example just came up [in a question today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953285/evaluation-of-macro).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lines with comments don't include a trailing `\`, so the macro definition stops at the first of them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the backslashes on your comment lines.